# EXPORT from GridPanel to Excel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ext.net, gridpanel

I am ext.net(Version 1.6) using vb.net (code Behind).
Please Take a look at my JavaScriptFunction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var saveData = function () {
         GridData.setValue(Ext.encode(GrdAppointment.getRowsValues({ selectedOnly: false })));
         alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
     };
</script>
```

GridData:

```
<ext:Hidden ID="GridData" runat="server" />
```

The problem am facing is that GridData is always empty and it seems that i can't find the right solution for this problem.
Thank You

Comment: So, do you see "Hello! I am an alert box!!" message? If so, please try "alert(GridData.getValue);". What do you see? Well, recalling your another question I feel that you call this JavaScript method from server side during a DirectEvent and expect the Hidden field gets its value during that same DirectEvent request, isn't that?

Comment: Hello Daniil! True that!!
i've tried "alert(GridData.getValue);"
And what i see:
`code` function (){if(!this.rendered){return this.value}var a=this.el.getValue();if(a===this.emptyText||a===undefined){a=""}return a} `code`

Comment: Sorry, should be "alert(GridData.getValue());". Please note that it is executed after a DirectEvent call. It is not possible to call a JavaScript function during some DirectEvent and get the result of that JavaScript function call during that same DirectEvent.

Comment: Daniil yes i've noticed that!!
thank you very much!! 
I used `code` <ext:Parameter Name="GridRows" Value="Ext.encode(#{GrdAppointment}.getRowsValues(false))" Mode="Raw" /> `code1 instead

Comment: Nice. I posted something as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you access a Hidden's value before updating. You might need to send a grid's data as an extra parameter of a DirectEvent.

Answer (score 1):

This control is WPF Specific, for more information refer to the WPF Specific topic

This topic explains how to implement data export to Excel using the xamDataPresenter™ control.

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/xamDataPresenter_Export_a_DataPresenter_Control_to_Excel.html